# Prevent Elementor Multi-Step Form textarea to change automatically to the next step

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I´m using the multi-step form from Elementor Pro. There is a little bug. If I have a textarea as single step, the textarea does not allow line breaks. If I press the ENTER key, it moves automatically to the next step. This is not a good practice for a textarea.

So I need a workaround for this because the project goes online next week.

```
$("textarea").on( "keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('textarea').val($('textarea').val()+'\n');
        return false;
    }
});
```

With the code above I create manually a new line and after this I return the function. This works in desktop devices, but not on mobile..

Do you have a better solution for this?

Comment: Maybe this will work for you `var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;` Since there is no "enter" key on mobiles I assume you refer to the `GO` key there is on many mobiles keyboard

Comment: Thanks, but with your solution it fires after pressing each button.. I only need the ENTER key and "Go" on smartphones. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You should use `var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;` and then `keycode == 13`

Answer (score 0):

Beside of [an extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-next-step-with-enter-in-elementor-forms/) that may work for you, there is another solution as follow:

- Give the form an `id` in the **Additional Options** section (for example **form_main**).
- Insert a HTML element on the page and add the following code in an `script` tag.

  ```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#form_main").off('keydown');
    })
  ```

[image: add script in html element]

Comment: Thanks. I am the developer of this extension :-)